BibTeX bibliography help
Here is my current document code. I am using Texifier program on MacOS with pdflatex.
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[scaled=.90]{helvet}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display] %Display chapters in Helvetica
  {\normalfont\sffamily\huge\bfseries}
  {\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
  
Text \cite{simmons_taking_2008}

\newpage
\bibliography{CommentaryOrigin.bib}
\bibliographystyle{chicago}
\end{document}

It prints my bibliography without numbers and in a style that I don't think is Chicago. Also in the text it prints a parenthetical citation with the authors name before it (so it's printed twice)? I just want it to be with footnotes correlating to a number in the bibliography, with correct Chicago formatting. I tried to look around for other help but I've resorted to asking myself. Thank you.
Edit: here is the BibTeX code for the citation. I imported it from Zotero... could that be why it's not being formatted correctly?

@misc{simmons_taking_2008,
    abstract = {At last, fossil and genetic findings elucidate the evolution of bats--and settle a long-standing debate over the origins of flight and echolocation},
    author = {Nancy B. Simmons},
    date-added = {2024-12-28 12:40:02 -0600},
    date-modified = {2024-12-28 13:19:10 -0600},
    file = {Snapshot:/Users/zachary/Zotero/storage/4QAQ2UAS/uncovering-bat-evolutionary-origins.html:text/html;tandf_iahb2040_463:/Users/zachary/Zotero/storage/TEAT8Z8K/tandf_iahb2040_463.ris:application/x-research-info-systems},
    journal = {Scientific American},
    language = {en},
    month = December,
    shorttitle = {Taking Wing},
    title = {Taking Wing: Uncovering the Evolutionary Origins of Bats},
    url = {https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/uncovering-bat-evolutionary-origins/},
    urldate = {2024-12-20},
    year = {2008},
    bdsk-url-1 = {https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/uncovering-bat-evolutionary-origins/}}


Welcome to TeX.SE. The BibTeX chicago bibliography style dates back to 1992 and implemented the then-current 13th ed. of the "Chicago Manual of Style". More than 30 years later, that's definitely no longer up to date -- as of late-2024, we're on the 17th edition of "Chicago". If you need to employ current "Chicago" formatting guidelines, you'll need to switch from natbib/bibtex to biblatex/biber. Please see the posting Biblatex is not performing shorthand chicago style citations for information on how to make the switch.

Ahh I see that makes so much sense. It didn’t even dawn on me that the package was probably written for an outdated Manual. After all though I decided to just compile my document as I was in Pages. I thought it might be helpful for me to learn LaTeX for the future, but I find myself spending more time with code and formatting than actual typing. Thank you for your help though!
